# safely resizing structs

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I would like some advice on safe ways to deal with struct's when the size of certain members are not known at code time.

For example I have a Struct Named "Channel". This struct has a member name "AudioSourceOBJ" which is a pointer to an an array of other struct type named "AudioSource". I wont know how many AudioSources I will have per channel until the program is run. I deal with that like this.

### channel object

```
struct channelobj {

        AudioUnitSampleType *leftoutput;
    AudioUnitSampleType *rightoutput;
    AudioSourceOBJ *audioSource;



};
```

### audiosource

```
struct audiosourceobj {


    AudioUnitSampleType   *leftoutput;
    AudioUnitSampleType   *rightoutput;


};
```

### creation of variable sized structs

```
void createInputs(ChannelOBJ channel,int numAudioInputs)
{
    channel->audioSource=(AudioSourceOBJ *)malloc(numAudioInputs * sizeof(AudioSourceOBJ));

    for (int i=0;i<numAudioInputs;i++)
    {
        AudioSourceOBJ obj;
        obj=newAudioSourceOBJ();
        channel->audioSource[i]=obj;

    }
}
```

I think this is o.k?

The problem I am now facing is that even though I can assign memory for the correct number of audio objects in my channel struct, the leftoutput and rightoutput arrays in the audiosource struct will not be set until later in the program.  They will be filled with an undermined amount of data, and are likely to change in size and content throughout the lifetime of the application.

Will I have to completely re malloc the channel containing the audiosource every time I want to make changes to a single audio object?

What is a safe way to do this or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Will I have to completely re malloc the channel containing the audiosource every time I want to make changes to a single audio object?"

No. You could for example replace the left output of the `i`th audio source like this:

```
free(channel->audioSource[i].leftoutput);
channel->audioSource[i].leftoutput = malloc(newSize * sizeof(AudioUnitSampleType));
```

Or even:

```
AudioUnitSampleType *tmp = realloc(channel->audioSource[i].leftoutput,
    newSize * sizeof(*tmp));
if (tmp == 0) { /* handle the error */ }
channel->audioSource[i].leftoutput = tmp;
```

By the way, if you don't post real code, it's possible that answers will contain errors due to errors in your examples.

There seems to be some confusion in your code between pointers and objects, for example the `channel` parameter is of type `ChannelOBJ`, then you use it as if it's a pointer. Is this an error, or is `ChannelOBJ` a typedef for `struct channelobj*`? It's generally better *not* to conceal that something is a pointer using a typedef.

If AudioUnitSampleType is likewise a pointer type, then my first code snippet above is incomplete, since it would then also be necessary to free the old objects pointed to by the elements of the array, and allocate new ones. The second one needs to free old ones *or* allocate new ones according to whether the size is being increased or decreased.

Comment: Yes ChannelOBJ is a typedef for struct channelobj. Why would you suggest not using typedef in this case?

Comment: @dubbeat: because C isn't Java ;-p. Actually, because people will frequently need to know whether a given type is "really" a pointer or not, whenever they're looking at code that acts on it. For instance, I needed to know what `AudioUnitSampleType` is in order to write my code snippets. Even if you use `ChannelOBJ` as a completely opaque type for clients of your API, and that's what appears in the header files they use, I would use `struct channelobj*` as the parameter in the implementation of the function, because in the function I need to know it's a pointer (to use `->` instead of `.`).

Comment: So, hiding that `ChannelOBJ` is pointer *might* be a useful abstraction for clients of your API, if they will treat it as a meaningless handle and only use it to pass into your functions. But it isn't a helpful abstraction once you get inside the `createInputs` function, it just hides something that I (the reader or the programmer) need to know. Abstractions should hide things that I *don't* need to know.

Comment: thumbs up for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't have to resize the allocated block of `AudioSourceObj` structs. `leftoutput` and `rightoutput` are merely pointers of a fixed size (not variable-sized arrays) and can be assigned an address by doing a separate `malloc`:

```
channel->audioSource[i].leftoutput = malloc(5 * sizeof(AudioUnitSampleType));
```